# Passing variables from template.php to page.tpl

Tags: drupal, variables, drupal-7

I'm very new to drupal and i need to query a table and pass a result from that query to my page.tpl file as a variable. Ive tried for hours but nothing i find works.

php code in template.php

```
<?php
 $result = db_select("SELECT COUNT(node.nid) AS num FROM node WHERE node.type = 'service'");
 foreach ($result as $record) {
    $number = $record->num;
 }
 return $number;
```

I even tried adding an `echo 'hello world';` but that didnt show up either.

Code in page.tpl

```
 <?php if ($number > 0) { ?>
    testing
 <?php } ?>
```

There are two nodes with the type as service. Any help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a hook in your template.php file.

For example (replace THEME_NAME with your theme's name):

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {   
    $vars['foo'] = "bar";
}
```

This will pass a variable called "foo" to your page.tpl.php file.

Comment: In addition to the above answer, you can put your first code to a function in template.php, and add a caching method (static $number) which would be faster. 
Also, as you have a COUNT in the sql query, $result will be a string - not an array.

Comment: No worries. Have a read about the preprocess hooks. It's quite useful.